# How to programmatically load a desired plugin on eclipse start up

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any method in SWT to programmatically set my plugin as default whenever the eclipse IDE starts i.e. when the eclipse starts a desired plugin is set as perspective.

Comment: Don't do this. I would instantly uninstall your stuff, as I like my workbench to come up with the perspective that was active on shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it should be possible with [`setDefaultPerspective(String id)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPerspectiveRegistry.html#setDefaultPerspective%28java.lang.String%29).

You can access this via:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry().setDefaultPerspective(id);
```

**However**, be careful when doing this. I can imagine that a lot of people might uninstall your plugin, just because they are annoyed by this small change.

Comment: ya u all r right it is really not desirable.I fully agree with u all.......its just meant for internal use only......